# Wildfly 10 error with EntityListeners. Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory - Argument resolvedBean must not be null

Tags: hibernate, jpa, wildfly, wildfly-10, jpa-2.1

Environment:

- Wildfly 10.1.0
- Java 9

I'm getting this error only by starting the project with a basic class and table.
The connection details works from the test in the web server.

Error when using javax.persistence.EntityListeners with Wildfly 10.

**Error log**

```
test00:10:10,328 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 72) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.persistenceunit."test.war#testPU": org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.persistenceunit."test.war#testPU": javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: testPU] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:179)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:121)
    at org.wildfly.security.manager.WildFlySecurityManager.doChecked(WildFlySecurityManager.java:667)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:193)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:320)
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: testPU] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.persistenceException(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:954)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:882)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.hibernate5.TwoPhaseBootstrapImpl.build(TwoPhaseBootstrapImpl.java:44)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:161)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.IllegalArgumentException: WELD-001456: Argument resolvedBean must not be null
    at org.jboss.weld.util.Preconditions.checkArgumentNotNull(Preconditions.java:40)
    at org.jboss.weld.manager.BeanManagerImpl.getInjectableReference(BeanManagerImpl.java:794)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.FieldInjectionPoint.inject(FieldInjectionPoint.java:92)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.Beans.injectBoundFields(Beans.java:364)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.Beans.injectFieldsAndInitializers(Beans.java:375)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.ResourceInjector$1.proceed(ResourceInjector.java:70)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.InjectionContextImpl.run(InjectionContextImpl.java:48)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.ResourceInjector.inject(ResourceInjector.java:72)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.BasicInjectionTarget.inject(BasicInjectionTarget.java:121)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.event.internal.jpa.ListenerFactoryBeanManagerStandardImpl$ListenerImpl.<init>(ListenerFactoryBeanManagerStandardImpl.java:84)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.event.internal.jpa.ListenerFactoryBeanManagerStandardImpl$ListenerImpl.<init>(ListenerFactoryBeanManagerStandardImpl.java:73)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.event.internal.jpa.ListenerFactoryBeanManagerStandardImpl.buildListener(ListenerFactoryBeanManagerStandardImpl.java:59)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.event.internal.jpa.CallbackBuilderLegacyImpl.resolveCallbacks(CallbackBuilderLegacyImpl.java:170)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.event.internal.jpa.CallbackBuilderLegacyImpl.buildCallbacksForEntity(CallbackBuilderLegacyImpl.java:69)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.event.spi.JpaIntegrator.integrate(JpaIntegrator.java:136)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:278)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:444)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:879)
    ... 9 more
```

**persistence.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="testPU" transaction-type="JTA">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>true</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    <class>es.roscam.light.business.reminders.entity.ToDo</class>
    <properties>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/roscam"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
      <property name="hibernate.cache.provider_class" value="org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider"/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

**Todo.java**

```
@Entity(name = "ToDo")
@NamedQuery(name = ToDo.findAll, query = "SELECT t FROM ToDo t")
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@EntityListeners(ToDoAuditor.class)
public class ToDo {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    static final String PREFIX = "reminders.entity.ToDo.";
    public static final String findAll = PREFIX + "findAll";

    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 2, max = 256)
    private String caption;
    private String description;
    private int priority;
    private boolean done;

    @Version
    private long version;
    ...
```

**ToDoManager.java**

```
@Stateless
public class ToDoManager {

    @PersistenceContext
    EntityManager em;

    public ToDo findById(long id) {
        return this.em.find(ToDo.class, id);

    }
    ...
```

Comment: @Table(name = "ToDo")  instead @Entity(name = "ToDo")

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the @EntityListeners.
I tried with payara and it works well, so it should be a problem with server wildfly.

I commented this line out and the server loads succesfully!